# sessionStorage.getItem not working when new browser open

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I am loading a login page,I am setting a sessionStorage value using

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {
window.sessionStorage.setItem("tab_value","test");
});
</script>
```

when login success page1.php loads and i am getting sessionStorage value using

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {
alert(window.sessionStorage.getItem("tab_value"));
});
</script>
```

but here,when new browser starts and after login it alerts `'null'` and it alerts `'test'` whenever I am login in the same tab after logout.
in my logout function I am trying to destroy session and calls the login page

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->load->view('login');
```

how to solve this thanks in advance

Comment: sessionStorage actually has nothing to do with a session, it should probably be called tabStorage...

Comment: I know but it does not work when new browser open and later it works.

Comment: it works when accessing by lan.I think its the problem of browser